# avplayerviewcontroller control events

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

On my view controller i have added a AVPlayerViewController as a child controller.

Its able to play both audio as well as video files from network. However i would like to capture the progress of the video/audio when a pause button or a back button is pressed. I am not sure what event to subscribe or what function to call nor could i find any on the documentation. Can someone show an example if possible?

Here is what i have on my view controller

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let mediaURL = URL(string:fileMediaUrl!)

        if let murl=mediaURL {
            self.avPlayer=AVPlayer(url:murl)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player=self.avPlayer
        }

        self.addChildViewController(avPlayerViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(avPlayerViewController.view)
        avPlayerViewController.view.frame=self.view.frame

        //this is of when media has finished playing
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer?.currentItem)

        avPlayer?.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should suscribe to `rate`. When `rate` is `0.0`, it means the player has stopped (for whatever reason).

```
avPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
```